# String processing: remove a prefix and capture all characters before a double-quote

Tags: command-line

I have this data

```
photo for Kurtis Hardy" data-
photo for Paul Hoven" data-sr
```

I would like filter this to only get the name in the middle.
I used this command to get those line

```
cat File| grep -E -o 'photo for.{0,20}'
```

Comment: "_get the name in the middle_". The name in the middle of the 30 characters you extracted? Or did you mean for example `Kurtis Hardy` and `Paul Hoven`? Are the double-quote characters are the person's name present in the data file? Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/698231/edit) to provide clarifications _as if you had provided them in the first place_. Do not respond in comments but instead make it easy for people to read your revised question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for cat here. [Leave the cat alone.](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award)

I'm assuming every name starts right after the "photo for " and ends with the first " as in your example. Let me know if that is not the case. Otherwise we will need to think more about what counts as a "name".

```
grep -E 'photo for [^"]{0,20}"' File | sed 's/photo for \([^"]\{0,20\}\)".*/\1/'
```

Or even simpler:

```
sed -n 's/photo for \([^"]\{0,20\}\)".*/\1/p' File
```

Comment: This is the best answer, thanks. I was able to get what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

## perl

```
cat File | perl -nE'm/^photo for ([^"]+)/ && say $1'
```

or

```
perl -nE'm/^photo for ([^"]+)/ && say $1' File
```

This strips the prefix `photo for`  and captures all characters up until `"`.